# Extracting users friend list from facebook graph api v2.3

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

I am using facebook SDK 4.0.1. I gave permission for user_friends but I am not able to get friend list of the user. I am getting the count of the user's friends but I want the name of the user's friends and ids

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mcallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
Log.d("Access Token", accessToken.toString());
Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
// Log.d("PROFILE","PROFILE IMAHE"+profile.getName());
displayWelcomeMessage(profile);

GraphRequestBatch batch = new GraphRequestBatch(
GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
@Override
public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse response) {
try {
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(Constant.KEY_ID,jsonObject.getString("id"));
editor.putString(Constant.KEY_USER_NAME,jsonObject.getString("name"));
editor.putString(Constant.KEY_USER_FNAME,jsonObject.getString("first_name"));
editor.putString(Constant.KEY_USER_LNAME,jsonObject.getString("last_name"));
// hometown = jsonObject.getJSONObject("hometown");
// editor.putString(Constant.KEY_USER_HOMETOWN,hometown.getString("name"));
editor.putString(Constant.KEY_USER_EMAIL,jsonObject.getString("email"));
editor.putString(Constant.KEY_USER_GENDER,jsonObject.getString("gender"));
// editor.putString(Constant.KEY_USER_DOB,jsonObject.getString("birthday"));

editor.commit();
// town = hometown.getString("name");
// personId = jsonObject.getString("id");
// gen = jsonObject.getString("gender");
// email = jsonObject.getString("email");
Log.d("RESPONCE", "RESPONCE user=" + jsonObject.toString());
Log.d("RESPONCE", "RESPONCE =" + response.toString());

}
catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}),
GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
@Override
public void onCompleted(JSONArray jsonArray, GraphResponse response) {
//Lo Application code for users friends
Log.d("RESPONCE FRIEND", "RESPONCE FRIEND=" + jsonArray.toString());
Log.d("RESPONCE FRIEND", "RESPONCE =" + response.toString());
response.getJSONArray();
}
}));
batch.addCallback(new GraphRequestBatch.Callback() {
@Override
public void onBatchCompleted(GraphRequestBatch graphRequests) {
// Application code for when the batch finishes
}
});
batch.executeAsync();
```

Comment: I believe that after recent API changes this is no longer allowed. The only friends you will be able to see are those who are also signed up to your app.

Comment: You can also use a script to scrape the data from the user's friend list, although that is technically against Facebook's policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since v2.0 of the Graph API, it is only possible to get friends who authorized your App too - for privacy reasons. More information can be found in this and many other threads about that exact same question: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)